# Axios response item with id 24628920206707414 or greater on the backend is turned to 24628920206707416

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, fetch-api

I have a react frontend where I am using the fetch api to get a API endpoint. If the id of the record is 24628920206707414 or greater, the id in the response is 24628920206707416.
My fetch call looks like this:

```
            fetch(`api-url`,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`},
                }
            )
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if(data){ 
                        setData(data)
                    }
                })
                .finally(() => { 
                    setLoading(false);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
                })
```

I have tried using axios instead like this:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(`api-url`, {
                        headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                        },            
                    });
                    setData(response.data);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                } finally {
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            };

            fetchData();
```

How can I handle IDs 24628920206707414 and greater? I have inspected the records retrieved on the backend where the API call is made and the IDs are correct there. I have also used curl to get the api endpoint from the command line and it returns the correct ids.

Comment: Use _strings_, very big numbers start getting mangled when parsed by JS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER